# Receiving notifications throughout user profiles

Tags: notifications, multi-user, profiles

I'm using 2 user profiles on my Android 12: 1 for my work apps, 1 for my personal apps. [image]

Recently I installed an app for my home security on my personal profile. Whenever my cameras recognize somebody (mailman, intruder etc.) I receive an notification in that app. However, at work I use my work profile, so I won't get any notifications from apps from my personal profile.

1. Is it possible to allow notifications from different user profiles, so that I get a notification from my security app from my personal profile, while using my work profile?
2. Is it possible to make my security app available for both profiles, without installing and setting it up twice?

Comment: When you say you have a Work profile, do you mean the same thing Google means about [Work Profile](https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/6191949?hl=en)? Because in a Work Profile this excerpt from [Google support](https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/7029561?hl=en) is valid: *When your work profile is running, your work apps can run and generate notifications that appear alongside your personal notifications*. However, from that screenshot in your question I think you have a separate user account which you use for Work related stuff. Correct?

Comment: If that's the case, than No, you can't get notification from your app installed in the primary user (Joe/You/Admin or any other name it has). When one user account is active other user accounts are suspended. So if Joe is active than Geek would be suspended and you wouldn't get notifications from it. Vice versa. See [Multi-user System Behavior](https://source.android.com/docs/devices/admin/multi-user#effects) for more info on this.